# Install Sencha cmd 4 Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to setup sencha cmd on ubuntu server:

I've fetched the archive:

`wget http://cdn.sencha.com/cmd/4.0.4.84/SenchaCmd-4.0.4.84-linux.run.zip`

however when I try to run the binary nothing happens:

`./SenchaCmd-4.0.4.84-linux.run`

Just returns the prompt with no errors or messages.

Judging by other guides I've found such as http://lubos.rendek.org/installation-and-getting-started-tutorial-with-sencha-ext-js-5-on-ubuntu-slash-debian-linux

It looks like this file invokes a wizard which. Since I'm using ubuntu server 14.04, X is not installed.

Am I downloading the wrong file? Or is there another step I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured it out by now, but it might help others:

You need to install ruby first with something like:

```
apt-get install ruby2.0
```

after that the wizard starts on the command line

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Installing Sencha Cmd Silently

Some users may wish to install Sencha Cmd without the installer’s GUI. If you need a CLI-only installation process, simply run the following command from your command line tool:

sudo SenchaCmd-5.x.y.z-linux.run **--mode unattended**

Source: http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/intro_to_cmd.html